Printing file's full path only on the first page and below the header
I am using Windows and want to print (right aligned) the full path of the running file only on the first page right below the right header as shown in the following screenshot.

Minimal Working Example
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    a5paper,
    hmargin=10mm,
    vmargin={0mm, 20mm},
    headheight=22mm, 
    headsep=5mm, 
    includehead,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{currfile}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[C]{{\bfseries\LARGE \LaTeX\ Corporation}\\
    {\footnotesize We can typset everything beautifully}\\  
    {\footnotesize from zero to hero}} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 
    
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize
    Crazy Frog Street 123, House 45\\
    Heaven 12345\\
    \textit{(beware of aggressive dogs)}} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize
    1234--5678--9101\\
    9876--5432--1012\\
    \textcopyright~2024 by Crazy Dogs}  
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
test
\CurrentFilePath
\end{document}


The currfile package provides support for absolute file names using the commands \currfileabsdir (directory) and \currfileabspath (full path including extension). Furthermore there is \currfilebase which is only the filename without extension (and without the path).
You can combine them to get the full path without the extension:
\currfileabsdir\currfilebase

This requires two things: first to load the currfile with the package option abspath, i.e., \usepackage[abspath]{currfile}, and second to run LaTeX with the special compiler flag --recorder, for example pdflatex --recorder yourfile.tex or lualatex --recorder yourfile.tex for pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX respectively.
If you don't run LaTeX from the terminal but from within an editor with a compile button or something similar then you should enable the --recorder option somewhere in the interface, similar to setting other options like --shell-escape (see How can I enable shell-escape?).
Then you can fine-tune the layout, in the code below I set the path right-aligned, shifted a bit up, and in red.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a5paper,
    hmargin=10mm,
    vmargin={0mm, 20mm},
    headheight=22mm, 
    headsep=5mm, 
    includehead,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[C]{{\bfseries\LARGE \LaTeX\ Corporation}\\
    {\footnotesize We can typset everything beautifully}\\  
    {\footnotesize from zero to hero}} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 
    
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize
    Crazy Frog Street 123, House 45\\
    Heaven 12345\\
    \textit{(beware of aggressive dogs)}} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize
    1234--5678--9101\\
    9876--5432--1012\\
    \textcopyright~2024 by Crazy Dogs}  
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-2.5Em}\rightline{\textcolor{red}{\currfileabsdir\currfilebase}}

Normal text

\end{document}

Result:

